# How to get return value in php class function

Tags: php, class

In my test. I have defined a class which has getLastTradeTime function

Here is class code:

```
<?php
namespace model;

//class Trade {//works fine
class Trade Extends \Mysql\Crud {// works fail
protected $table = 'ms_trade';
protected $pk    = 'id';
private $hh;// hh is not related to class /Crud

 public function getLastTradeTime($uid, $ip) {
    $this->hh="stringtest";
    return $this->hh;
}
}
```

Now I want to call this class function, I should get "stringtest" return.

But It is unlucky, there is nothing i have got.

Here is html code:

```
<body style="height:100%" >

<?php 
include "o1ws1v/class/model/Trade.php";
$trade_model = new \model\Trade();

$lastTrade_time = $trade_model->getLastTradeTime("654651","127.0.0.1");
echo $lastTrade_time;
?>
</body>
```

I mean it is simply class, and normal way to call function. It seems nothing wrong

Who can give me a favor

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: So what do you see when you run your code?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variable `$hh` after `$pk` ? Just try `private $hh;` then in the function `$this->hh = 'stringtest'; `

Comment: Turn on error reporting(`error_reporting(E_ALL);` and
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the start of the script) and check that the class is loaded (I tend to use `require_once` or an autoloader for classes)

Comment: @lovelace, sorry, I have made a mistake. class Trade Extends another class 
 \Mysql\Crud is the reason, see my update.

Comment: @u_mulder, thank you, I had made mistake,  see my update

Comment: @LiamG, You are right, I have added this. And I made a mistake. see my update. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i am not having namespace model so i removed it.
It seems that something wrong with your path. ("o1ws1v/class/model/Trade.php")
Kindly double check it.
below code is working using below files.
1.Trade.php

```
<?php
class Trade {
    protected $table = 'ms_trade';
    protected $pk    = 'id';

    public function getLastTradeTime($uid, $ip) {
        $hh="stringtest";
        return $hh;
    }
}
?>
```

2.child.php

```
<?php
include "Trade.php";
$trade_model = new Trade();
$lastTrade_time = $trade_model->getLastTradeTime("654651","127.0.0.1");
//can also called as below.
//$lastTrade_time = $trade_model::getLastTradeTime("654651","127.0.0.1");
echo $lastTrade_time;
?>
```

call child file in your server.
if you having any query, feel free to ask.